# How can I make a one line generator expression to generate these two different lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program which parses lists like this.

```
['ecl:gry', 'pid:860033327', 'eyr:2020', 'hcl:#fffffd', 'byr:1937', 'iyr:2017', 'cid:147', 'hgt:183cm']
```

I want to turn this list into a dictionary of the key value pairs which I have done here:

```
keys = []
values = []

for string in data:
    pair = string.split(':')
    keys.append(pair[0])
    values.append(pair[1])

zipped = zip(keys, values)
self.dic = dict(zipped)
print(self.dic)
```

I know that I can use list comprehension to make one of the lists at a time like this

```
keys = [s.split(':')[0] for s in data]
values = [s.split(':')[1] for s in data]
```

This requires two loops so the first code example would be better, but is there a way to generate both lists using one generator with unpacking and then zip the two together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
l = ['ecl:gry', 'pid:860033327', 'eyr:2020', 'hcl:#fffffd',
     'byr:1937', 'iyr:2017', 'cid:147', 'hgt:183cm']

dict(e.split(':') for e in l)
```

Comment: You don't even need the list: `dict(e.split(':') for e in l)`

Comment: Even less characters in the answer. Thank you guys

Comment: Less characters doesn't mean that it will run faster. But in this case it will be faster because the `split` has to be done only once per string.

Comment: @Matthias I think less characters generally means it will run faster. In this case, it won't create a temporary list and pass the generator directly to the `dict` which makes it a little bit faster.

Comment: My comment wasn't about this solution. Often people try to cram everything in as few lines as possible because they think that less code means a faster runtime behaviour. But here I really would measure the time difference between the list and the generator. I've seen cases where the speed was faster with the intermediate construction of a list. I can try to find an example.

Comment: @Matthias In addition to what you said; even if something is fewer characters, it doesn't mean it is better because *readability counts* :)

Answer (score 2):

You can dict comprehension it easily:

```
your_dict = {x.split(':')[0]: x.split(':')[1] for x in data}
```

You can also prevent from using split two times and use generator:

```
your_dict = dict(x.split(':') for x in data)
```

Which seems even cleaner...

Comment: Wow I didn't even think there was dictionary comprehension, that is amazing. Python is beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: This was my first idea, but using `split` twice seemed kind of ... clumsy.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```py
self.dic = {}
for e in data:
    k, v = e.split(':')
    self.dic[k] = v
```